# How to return Generic List with Generic Class Object in c#?

Tags: c#, generics, return, generic-list, generic-collections

I want to return Table List with there class object and this call also generic, I don't want to use any Non-Strong type List like ArrayList on any other.

```
        public List<T> GetTables()
        {
            var tbls = new List<T>();
            tbls.Add(new Table<Table1>() { Name = "Table1"});
            tbls.Add(new Table<Table2>() { Name = "Table2"});
            tbls.Add(new Table<Table3>() { Name = "Table3"});
            return tbls;
        }
```

in above Method, Table1, Table2, and any type table class object... There classes has no any based class, These classes use to Set of table properties with custom format.

I want to return it.

Please help me if anyone have any idea.

thank you.

Comment: Do Table1, Table2 and Table3 have a common base type?

Comment: No, Table1, Table2 and Table3 is not Common based type.

Comment: If they don't all inherit from a common base type and it's not a `List<CommonBaseType>` then the above is not possible how you want it. Substitute "interface" for "base type" in my prior sentence if we're talking about interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use generic type with the List without specifying type parameter explicitly. Alternatively, you can create a base class or interface that would be a parameter for the List.

I mean:

```
        public static List<ITable> GetTables()
        {
            var tbls = new List<ITable>();
            tbls.Add(new Table<Table1> { Name = "Table1"});
            tbls.Add(new Table<Table2> { Name = "Table2"});
            tbls.Add(new Table<Table3> { Name = "Table3"});
            return tbls;
        }

        public class Table<T> : ITable
        {
            public T TableInstance { get; set; }
            public Type TableType => typeof(T);
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }

        public interface ITable
        {
            Type TableType { get; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you @konstanin. but the issue is i still need to pass Table1, table to while accessing "TableInstance". I want this Direct access. I have idea is it possible or not.

Comment: i want like this.  public void Run()
        {
            var lst = GetTables();
            foreach (var item in lst)
            {
                item.TableInstance.GenerateData();
            }
        }

Comment: @AshishSojitra - If you want to do that then you must have a common base type or interface.

Comment: Thanks @Konstantin-Dubrovnyi
Based on your idea, Now i can move forward. But still there is an one method i can't access based on above idea.

"void GenerateData(T data)"

But it not big deal, I can move forward without this method.

Thank you again to both of you.

Comment: @AshishSojitra then you may do the following: create base class or interface (ITableInstance) from Table1, Table2, Table3 with method GenerateData(), create List<ITable<ITableIntance>> and use it like you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

If the only common thing of the list's components is that they are `Table<>` generic objects, if there isn't any interface or common base class between `Table1`/`Table2`/`Table2`, you can simply treat them as `object`:

```cs
        public List<Table<IGenerateData>> GetTables()
        {
            var tbls = new List<Table<IGenerateData>>();
            tbls.Add(new Table<Table1>() { Name = "Table1"});
            tbls.Add(new Table<Table2>() { Name = "Table2"});
            tbls.Add(new Table<Table3>() { Name = "Table3"});
            return tbls;
        }

        public interface IGenerateData
        {
            void GenerateData();
        }

        public class Table1 : IGenerateData
        {           
        }
```

Comment: I want to use Strong type, not a Object type.

Comment: As you suggest on another comment, you need to access the method `GenerateData()` on `Table1` ... `Table3`... so you can create an Interface `IGenerateData` with the method, and make `Table1` ... `Table3` implement that interface. Then your list could be `List<Table<IGenerateData>>`

Comment: Thanks @CicheR.

Based on your idea, Now i can move forward. But still there is an one method i can't access based on above idea.

"void GenerateData(T data)"

But it not big deal, I can move forward without this method.

Thank you again to both of you.